# Horizontal image scroller setChildIndex only affects every other nested movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This image scroller is made of a container mc which holds 7 movieclips that each has an image and a border. The border goes from alpha 0 to 1 on each arrow key press (from another class). The scroller itself works until I try to setChildIndex of 'next' to container.numChildren -1. Then it affects every other mc and screws it all up. Is there a better way to achieve this forward backward scroller? Thanks for any advice. What I'm trying to achieve is to have each 'holder' be the top depth inside container.

```
package 
{
import com.greensock.TweenMax;  
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;    

public class ImageBank extends MovieClip
{
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var req:URLRequest;
    private var container:Sprite;
    private var border:Border;
    private var holder:Sprite;
    private var numImages;
    private var currentImage:uint = 0;
    private var prevImage:uint;
    private var borderNext:*;
    private var borderLast:*;       

    public function ImageBank(path:String, numImages:uint)
    {
        this.numImages = numImages          
        container = new Sprite()
        addChild(container);            

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        border = new Border();
        border.alpha = 0;
        holder = new Sprite()
        holder.x = i * 165;
        loader = new Loader()
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);                
        req = new URLRequest(path + 'poster_' + i + '.png');
        loader.load(req);
        loader.x += 4;
        loader.y += 3;
        loader.alpha = .8;
        holder.addChild(border);
        holder.addChild(loader);
        container.addChild(holder);

        }   

    }

    public function removeBorder():void {
        TweenMax.to(borderNext, .4, {alpha:0});
    }

    public function tweenNext():void {

        var next = container.getChildAt(currentImage);          
        TweenMax.to(next, .4, {transformAroundCenter:{scale:1.1}});
        container.setChildIndex(next, container.numChildren-1);     
        borderNext = next.getChildAt(0)
        TweenMax.to(borderNext, .4, {alpha:1});         
        if (currentImage > 0) {             
            var last = container.getChildAt(currentImage-1);
            TweenMax.to(last, .4, {transformAroundCenter:{scale:1}});               
            borderLast = last.getChildAt(0)
            TweenMax.to(borderLast, .5, {alpha:0});             
        }

        if (currentImage < 6){              
            currentImage ++;
            prevImage = currentImage -1
        }           
    }

    public function tweenPrev():void {  

        var next = container.getChildAt(prevImage);
        TweenMax.to(next, .4, {transformAroundCenter:{scale:1.1}});
        container.setChildIndex(next, container.numChildren-1);         
        var borderNext = next.getChildAt(0)
        TweenMax.to(borderNext, .5, {alpha:1});

        if (prevImage < 7) {                
            var last = container.getChildAt(prevImage+1);
            TweenMax.to(last, .4, {transformAroundCenter:{scale:1}});               
            var borderLast = last.getChildAt(0)
            TweenMax.to(borderLast, 1, {alpha:0});              
        }
        if (prevImage > 0) {                
            prevImage --;
            currentImage --;
        }       

    }


    private function onLoaded(event:Event):void {           
        //loaded
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Do you just want to bring the next display objec to the fron without affecting the rest ot them? try container.addchild(next) instead of setChildIndex. this won't touch the rest of them.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too, but again it is affecting 1st, 3rd, 5th image. Not sure why.